# Magento 1.9 - Can't edit customer in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

I have only one customer which is me. I tried to edit the name and I get redirected to the startpage of the backend and the error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setAttribute() on boolean in /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 80` is logged.

This is the line: `$dataModel->setAttribute($attribute);`

I logged $attribute and get this:

```
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )
```

Im not sure what causes this error and how to solve it, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out the cause of this error, it was quite hard to track.

I made a network analysis with chrome developer console and found out that there is a 500 status code in the request `?isAjax`.

At first I logged the value of $attribute in the factory function:

**app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data.php**

```
public static function factory(Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute $attribute, Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $entity)
{
    Mage::Log($attribute->getData('attribute_code'), 7, "eav.log");
    ...
```

This showed me the value `customattribute` so I knew something is wrong with it. So I found out that this is an old attribute which I added for test once. So I opened phpmyadmin and deleted this attribute from the table `eav_attribute`.

I found it there by searching the whole database by using phpmyadmins search:

[image]
[image]

Now I tried to edit the customer again and save, but then the loading box with "please wait..." showed forever.

So I made the network analysis again and found out that isAjax gives status code 200 now.
So now it must be another issue which is not caused by serverside code.

So I checked the response of that request and found out that it returned a json object which is fine. But there was also a error message attached just next to the json object, which is the reason why the json object was "corrupted" and so the javascript was unable to process successfully.

I immediately knew why this error was there. It was because I am using a debug code in the index.php which renders all magento errors. So I commented it out and now it works again:

```
//ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
//register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
//
//function fatal_handler() {
//    $error = error_get_last();
//    if ($error) {
//        echo("<pre>");
//        print_r($error);
//    }
//}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Please find customer_eav_attribute and note down all the attribute ids from this table.
> 2. Then find the eav_attribute table and check all the attribute id from this table.
> 3. Check the frontend_input column has not blank or null value of the attribute id which is got from the customer_eav_attribute table. 
>      4.If any attribute has blank or null value for the column frontend_input then add any of the input type in their place.
> 4. Then check the issue.

Comment: Thx for the hint, I think I located the problem. I logged the value of $attribute and it said "customattribute" for the attribute_code. This is an attribute code which I added through an extension. I think its install script is not working. I will investigate and report back.

Comment: Basically you wanted me to execute this SQL Statement: `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE frontend_input is NULL AND attribute_id IN (SELECT attribute_id FROM customer_eav_attribute)`. This only returned `customattribute`, I deleted it, but now it is stuck in "Please wait"... if I try to edit a customer and save. I will investigate further.

Comment: I found the cause for this and created an answer. Thx for your help, you teached me something today sir

Comment: it's my pleasure,
please accept if it is helpful

Comment: I will accept my own answer in two days since it contains all infos needed to solve it.